# ArgoUML2 startup issue from top level directory

Tags: executable-jar, ubuntu-14.04, argouml

I am not a java expert. I have downloaded the ArgoUML and extracted it. Under `~/argouml` directory I can find the main executable file 'argouml2.sh'. If I go into the directory and run, it executes fine.

Problem is if I execute the program from another directory with absolute path; then it is showing a kind of error message telling this is an experimental version.

Strange !!! :)

Eg:

```
cd ~
argouml/argouml2.sh
```

or

```
/home/myname/argouml/argouml2.sh
```

[image]

and in side bar..

[image]

Why this message comes only when I execute the program from different path other than its location?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an `argouml.sh` file to run standard ArgoUML version.  The `argouml2.sh` file is, as its name implies, to run the experimental (and incomplete) UML 2.x version.  I'm not sure what's going on with the difference in behavior based on the default directory, but the basic problem is you're running the wrong version.